# How do I use dynamic-DNS in environment like this?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, dynamic-ip, dynamic-dns

I'm really new to networking.

I have somewhat nice internet connection(in my standards, that is).

But I can't configure the router. 
(The internet connection is not mine, and its settings page is password-protected)

I'm trying to use ddclient, but I don't know how it could work without configuring port forwarding.
(my internet connection uses dynamic ip...(and it's shared by A LOT of computers...)

Is there an answer to this??? Or should I contact the network admin?
(which is what I want to avoid at all cost - except spending money.)

BTW, I'm currently using UBUNTU 11.04 and/or Debian OS(the latest stable one)

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is probably going to be migrated over to SuperUser.com. From the Server Fault FAQ: Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.

Comment: ...?   I thought this question IS server related question;;;(I'm trying to run a server out of Ubuntu 11.04...) I thought SuperUser.com is about Windows Registry and Linux power-hacks and stuff... I'm really confused about this stackexchange websites T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic DNS only requires you to be able to make *outgoing* connections. This means you won't need to forward any ports (port forwards are for incoming connections).

When you make a connection to your DNS provider, it can see which IP you're using to connect and adjust your dynamic domain accordingly.

Comment: But last time I used dynamic dns at home, I had to use port-forwarding...also, I'm trying to use dynamic-dns to remotely access the computer outside the network. (So I really need incoming connections) but anyway, thanks for the lightning fast reply:)

Comment: dynamic DNS just points to your internet connection. you would need to use port forwarding to actually make any connections to that internet connection :)

Comment: So...does that mean I have to contact the net admin???(plz no)

Comment: you can also try an app like localtunnel: http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

Comment: ...my savior!!!